# How do I enable autocomplete for chrome-types in my Typescript Vue-component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple vue-component that I'm gonna use as an extension-popup, but I can't seem to access the chrome extension APIs from inside the .vue-file.

The component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <button @click="handleClick"> Hey and ho </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick() {
            // example of code I'd like to use here, which WORKS, 
            // but vetur tells me it doesn't exist
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                    tabs[0].id,
                    {code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";'}
                );
            });
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

Now, when I build and run the extension, the button **works**, but it's quite annoying having to run the code every single change I make, because I don't know if I spelled something correctly.

I have installed `@types/chrome`, and these work in other `.ts`-files, just not in `.vue`-files

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you NPM installed @types/chrome?

Comment: Yep, I'll put that in the question as well, but good suggestion.

Comment: you should check out `webextension-pollyfill-ts`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help, as the problem is in VSCode, and not in running the code.

Comment: If it works in .ts files, then possible a mis-configuration in your tsconfig.json file. In my case, I see I have a specific "src/**/*.vue" reference in the include tag. Also, link to a Vetur reference that may help if you've not seen it: https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/setup.html#extensions

Comment: Didn't find anything that fixed the issue, but can I ask @IanAsh : Do you have a chrome-extension project in vue, where you are allowed to use the chrome-object? I can't figure out what else to google, but if it works for others, then I know the porblem is on my end.

Comment: @SebastianVittersø Using VSC/Vetur for VueJS + Vuetify project in TS where Intellisense works fine, but not done anything that uses chrome-extension.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue here using Vite, Vue3 and TS.

To solve this problem, after installing `@types/chrome` as a devDependency, you need to specify it under `types` in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"types": ["@types/chrome"],
```

Then you can use this in the script section of your `.vue` files.

Comment: I won't be accepting the answer as I don't know whether it fixed my issue (no longer have the project on my machine), and things have surely changed alot considering we now use volar instead of vetur. I'll upvote your answer, though, as it might've fixed the issue then, and I trust it fixed it for you. Thanks!